# Can i select all columns except a specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle

**test_table**:

```
id   f_name     l_name  age  
--  --------- --------   ------
```

I am new to oracle, but if I want to select all the columns I should use

```
select * from test_table
```

however if I want to select all the columns except age I should write

```
select id, f_name, l_name from test_table
```

Is there a way I can select all the columns but disgarding a column or two?

Because in my work busninse there alot of columns and sometimes I don't need to select them all.

Comment: You should always specify all the columns you need - don't use `SELECT *` in production-level code.

Comment: @amit singh i am not using the same talbes everytime

Comment: than u dont have  choice...or .create views of each table...

Comment: @AmitSingh maybe your are right i have to stick with views thanks

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you are right i should be carefull more with my questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

The only thing that comes into my mind is to create a `VIEW` for your `SELECT` statement.

```
CREATE VIEW employeeList
AS
SELECT id, f_name, l_name -- <<== select only the column you want to project
FROM  test_table;
```

once your `VIEW` is created, you can now use `*` against the view,

```
SELECT * FROM employeeList
```

Comment: i have different tables , every time i write a procedure or a querry i have to use different table or column to get specific data or result, so view doenst help me all the time

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Either you can `SELECT *` or you can define which columns you want to select. There is no such SELECT clause in oracle that allows you to return all columns except some automatically. [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)